# How to customize the output for mask r-cnn's display_instances() function

Tags: python, faster-rcnn

How to use display_instances() function to only draw the mask WITHOUT the bounding boxes and the vice-versa?

```
visualize.display_instances(image=image, 
                                  boxes=r['rois'], 
                                  masks=r['masks'], 
                                  class_ids=r['class_ids'], 
                                  class_names=class_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the visualize.py to the following version which has an option to show mask or bbox.
[updated visualize.py here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/tree/3deaec5d902d16e1daf56b62d5971d428dc920bc)

However the label section needs to be modified as follows:

```
# Label
        if not captions:
            class_id = class_ids[i]
            score = scores[i] if scores is not None else None
            label = class_names[class_id]
            caption = "{} {:.3f}".format(label, score) if score else label
            ax.text(x1, y1 + 8, caption,
                color="none", size=11, backgroundcolor="none") # to  remove captions change to: color= "none"

        else:
            caption = captions[i]
            ax.text(x1, y1 + 8, caption,
                color='w', size=11, backgroundcolor="none") # to  remove captions change to: color= "none"
```